# ¿Cómo puedo guardar las entradas de un usuario de un TextBox?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un `WinForm` en el cual tengo 2 `TextBox`.

El usuario puede entrar datos en estos 2 `TextBox`.

Lo que busco hacer es que a cada ejecución del `WinForm`, lo que se haya entrado como `input` en estos 2 `TextBox` sean guardados desde su última ejecución.

¿Cómo podría realizar esto?

He visto varios sitios dando soluciones pero ninguna de ellas me logra guardar.

Comment: Usa el registro del sistema.

Comment: pero cual seria el medio persistente? sera un archivo de texto, o una base de datos

Comment: ¿Ocupas todos los datos anteriores o sólo el último?

Comment: Intentas autocompletar el Textbox con los valores?

Answer (score 3):

Se puede usar el registro de windows, es muy sencillo

Primero, hay que guardar. Se puede guardar al momento que el usuario escribe o al momento de cerrar el formulario, es decir, el evento `KeyPress` de los `TextBox` o el unload/close del formulario en cualquier caso, sería:

```
RegSettings.SaveSetting("nombresistema", "nombreparametro", mitextbox.Text);
```

Luego, al inicializar el formulario se pueden obtener los valores con `GetSetting`

```
  mitextbox.Text = RegSettings.GetSetting("nombresitema", "nombreparametro", valorpordefecto);
```

Yo utilizo una clase de ayuda que es la siguiente:

```
public class RegSettings
    {
        private static string FormRegKey(string sSect)
        {
            return sSect;
        }

        public static void SaveSetting(string Section, string Key, string Setting)
        {

            string text1 = FormRegKey(Section);
            RegistryKey key1 = Application.UserAppDataRegistry.CreateSubKey(text1);
            if (key1 == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                key1.SetValue(Key, Setting);
            }
            catch (Exception exception1)
            {
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                key1.Close();
            }

        }
        public static string GetSetting(string Section, string Key, string Default)
        {
            if (Default == null)
            {
                Default = "";
            }
            string text2 = FormRegKey(Section);
            RegistryKey key1 = Application.UserAppDataRegistry.OpenSubKey(text2);
            if (key1 != null)
            {
                object obj1 = key1.GetValue(Key, Default);
                key1.Close();
                if (obj1 != null)
                {
                    if (!(obj1 is string))
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return (string)obj1;
                }
                return null;
            }
            return Default;
        }

    }
```

Comment: de verdad la registry de windows? que pasa si la aplicacion no ejecuta como admin de la pc? en ese caso no tendra acceso. La verdad no recomendaria persistir en el registry

Comment: no es recomendable esto, coincido con @LeandroTuttini es peligroso y hasta podrías no tener permisos para guardar datos en el registry.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que podrías solucionar fácilmente tu problema utilizando las Settings (Configuración).

Intrucciones con imágenes a continuación:

1. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
6. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
7. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
8. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo en snippet el código C#:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Caja1;
            TextBox2.Text = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Caja2;
        }

        private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Caja1 = TextBox1.Text;
            WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Caja2 = TextBox2.Text;
            WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si solo necesitas persistir los datos de una ejecución puedes usar [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) o puedes crear tu mismo un archivo plain text o xml.

Si necesitas persistir más datos que los de la última ejecución puedes usar una db tipo sqlite

Como bien han dicho, usar el registro de windows conlleva que tengas que hacer la aplicación con permisos de administrador. Personalmente jamás usaría el registro para persistir datos que no fueran de la propia instalación del programa.

Ejemplo muy breve, tienes más información si buscas por ConfigurationManager:

Controller class (sólo por tenerlo ordenado y por extensible, pero, por supuesto, esta clase no es necesaria)

```
public static class ConfigurationController
{
    public static Configuration Config { get; set; }

    static ConfigurationController()
    {
        Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

         if (Config == null)
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Config File not found");
    }
}
```

Ejemplo de uso

```
String serverValue = ConfigurationController.Config.AppSettings.Settings["Server"].Value;

ConfigurationController.Config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Home","127.0.0.1");

ConfigurationController.Config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("Server");
ConfigurationController.Config.Save();
```

Comment: podrías agregar un ejemplo de esto que mencionas?

Comment: Tienes razón @Alan, modificada mi respuesta.