# ¿Como guardar y acceder a las entradas de Configuracion de mi App en c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en C# y vengo desde vb.net y cada paso es un desafío.

Ahora no encuentro la forma de hacer algo tan sencillo como era `GetSetting` y `SaveSetting` antes.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Consulté este enlace pero no me funciona eso, tal vez porque estoy usando Visual Studio 2019: [¿Cómo puedo guardar las entradas de un usuario de un TextBox?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/27060/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-guardar-las-entradas-de-un-usuario-de-un-textbox/27064#27064)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas de almacenar datos entre un inicio y otro de la aplicación. Imagino que te refieres con `GetSetting` y `SaveSetting` a las funciones de acceso a entradas en el *Windows Registry*. Si es así, en C# puedes utilizar las clases `RegistryKey` y `Registry`.

Para leer una entrada puedes utilizar directamente el método estático `GetValue` de la clase `Registry`, definida en el *namespace* `Microsoft.Win32`. Para escribir tienes entonces el método `SetValue`.

Tienes la documentación con unos ejemplos aquí: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=net-5.0.

También puedes utilizar métodos un poco más complejos pero que permiten mejorar las prestaciones y dan más flexibilidad utilizando la clase `RegistryKey`. Este ejemplo te muestra cómo leer un valor:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MiEmpresa\MiPrograma\MisDatos");

if (key != null)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine(key.GetValue("MiSetting1"));
    Console.WriteLine(key.GetValue("MiSetting2"));
    key.Close();  
}
```

Para escribir sería similar a esto:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MiEmpresa\MiPrograma\MisDatos"); 

//storing the values  
key.SetValue("MiSetting1", "Mi dato 1");
key.SetValue("MiSetting2", "Mi dato 2");
key.Close();
```

La documentación la puedes encontrar aquí: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?view=net-5.0

Comment: Es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Muchisimas gracias y fui para la segunda opcion (RegistryKey) !